# self.gridrange=8 is showing as a tuple when I want it to be an integer

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import math
import random
#positions are stored in label and number format
    LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

positions = ['label'+str(i)+str(j) for i in range(8) for j in range(8)]

class Application(tk.Frame):
    global positions
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W) 

        #The entry screen

        #label = tk.Label(self, text="""Begin.""", font=LARGE_FONT)
        #label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)
        #label = tk.Label(self, text="""Exit.""", font=LARGE_FONT)

        #label.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10)
        #button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Game", command=self.start)
        #button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Quit Game", command=quit)
        #button1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
        #button2.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=1)

    #def start(self):
        #self.createWidgets()

        self.master = master
        app = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="yellow")
        app.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        app.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        app.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
# instructions and fonts
        self.instructions = "Find the hidden treasure!\n\nUse the arrow keys to select where to look, then press Enter to check. \
        There is a 50/50 chance you will be told the distance from the treasure. Keep hunting until you find it. Good luck!"
# create instructions widget
        self.info = tk.Text(app, padx=10, pady=10,width=15,bd=0, height=19, bg="yellow")
        self.info.insert(1.0,self.instructions)
        self.info.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='N'+'E'+'S'+'W')
# create island widget
        self.island = tk.Text(app, bg="cyan", padx=40, pady=40, width=15, height=9, bd=0)
        self.island.insert(1.0, "ready")
        self.island.grid(row=0,column=1, stick='N'+'E'+'S'+'W', rowspan=3)
# restart button
        #self.restart_b = tk.Button(app, text="Restart", bg="red", command=self.begin)  
        #self.restart_b.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20)
# score labels and fields
        self.score_lbl = tk.Label(app, text="Guesses: 0", bg="yellow")
        self.score_lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)

        #keep track og gold
        self.gold_lbl = tk.Label(app, text="Gold: 0", bg="yellow")
        self.gold_lbl.grid(row=3, column=0)

        #gold and bandit positions


        self.gridrange = 8
        self.numchest = 10
        self.bandits = 3
        self.winscore = 100

# set keydown handler
        root.bind("<Key>", self.key_pressed)
# best score variable
        self.best_score = 0
# begin game
        #self.begin()
#print self.treasure_pos
        self.mainMenu()


    def mainMenu(self):
        self.t = tk.Toplevel(self.master, backgroun='red')
        self.t.wm_title("Main Menu")
        self.l = tk.Label(self.t, text="Welcome to Treasure Hunt", background='red')
        self.l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)
        self.t.lift(self.master)
        #self.t.geometry('640x480+0+0')
        self.play = tk.Button(self.t, text="play", bg="purple", command=self.letsplay)
        self.play.pack(side='left', expand=True)
        self.ops = tk.Button(self.t, text="options", bg="yellow", command=self.ops)
        self.ops.pack(side='left', expand=True)

    def ops(self):
        self.opwin = tk.Toplevel(self.master, backgroun='red')
        self.opwin.wm_title("Option Menu")
        self.opl = tk.Label(self.opwin, text="Welcome to Treasure Hunt", background='red')
        self.opl.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)
        self.opwin.lift()
        #self.opwin.geometry('640x480+0+0')
        self.appp = tk.Button(self.opwin, text="Apply", bg="purple", command=self.letsplay)
        self.appp.pack(side='left', expand=True)
        self.gridops = tk.Listbox(self.opwin, selectmode='SINGLE')
        self.gridops.pack()
        for i in range(6, 14):
            self.gridops.insert(tk.END, i)
        self.gridrange = self.gridops.curselection()

    def letsplay(self):
        self.t.destroy()
        #self.opwin.destroy()
        #self.begin()
        self.createWidgets()
        root.lift()       

    def createWidgets(self):






        #print (self.gridrange)
        root.lift()
        root.after_cancel(self.tick)
        self.matrix = [["#" for col in range(self.gridrange)] for row in range(self.gridrange)]

        self.current_pos = [0,0]
        self.treasure_pos = []
        self.bandit_pos = []

        #times treasure has been found
        self.treasures_won = []
        self.last_treasure = []

        self.gold_found = 0
        for i in range(0, self.numchest):
            self.gold_xy = self.get_pos()
            self.treasure_pos.append(self.gold_xy)
        for i in self.treasure_pos:
            print (i)
        print (len(self.treasure_pos))
        for i in range (0, self.bandits):
            self.bandit_xy = self.get_pos()
            self.bandit_pos.append(self.bandit_xy)
        for i in self.bandit_pos:
            print (i)
        print (len(self.bandit_pos))
        #self.treasure_pos = [0,0]
        #print self.treasure_pos
        self.sett()






        top=self.winfo_toplevel()
        self.entry_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.entry_frame.grid(row=0, column=0,rowspan=1,columnspan=8,sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)


        self.pos_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.pos_frame.grid(row=1, column=0,columnspan=8,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)

        self.entry_frame.rowconfigure(0,weight=2)

        screenx=self.pos_frame.winfo_width()
        screeny=self.pos_frame.winfo_height()
        for i in range(8):            
            top.rowconfigure(i,weight=1)
            top.columnconfigure(i,weight=1)
            self.pos_frame.columnconfigure(i,weight=1)
            self.pos_frame.rowconfigure(i,weight=1)
            self.entry_frame.columnconfigure(i,weight=1)
            self.rowconfigure(i,weight=1)
            self.columnconfigure(i,weight=1)
        self.label_no_of_moves=tk.Label(self.entry_frame,text="MOVES : ")
        self.label_no_of_moves.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.moves=tk.StringVar()        
        self.number_of_moves=tk.Entry(self.entry_frame,textvariable=self.moves)
        self.number_of_moves.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.label_direction=tk.Label(self.entry_frame,text="DIRECTION : ")
        self.label_direction.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)

    #Assume Direction to be U D L R you can also use listbox here but i m not using it for saving time

        self.dir=tk.StringVar()        
        self.direction=tk.Entry(self.entry_frame,textvariable=self.dir)
        self.direction.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.direction=tk.Button(self.entry_frame,text='GO',command=self.gomoves)
        self.direction.grid(row=0,column=4,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):

                x='label'+str(i)+str(j)
                self.x=tk.Label(self.pos_frame,bg="#"+"F"+str(5*(1+i))[0]+str(4*(i+1))[0]+str(6*(j+2))[0]+str(3*(j+1))[0]+"7",text=str(i)+str(j))
                self.x.grid(row=i,column=j,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)

    #For updating the grid if window size is changed

        self.bind('<Configure>',self.update)

    #For initial Player position

        self.start_position=str('label'+generate_initial_position())
        self.current_position = self.start_position
        print (self.current_position)

    #initial position removed from positions(avaliable positions)

        print (positions)
        positions.remove(str(self.start_position))

    #selecting treasure chest from remaining positions

        self.treasure_chest_positions=random.sample(positions,10)

    #removing treasures chest position from positions(avaliable positions)

        for i in positions[:]:
            if i in self.treasure_chest_positions:
                positions.remove(i)
        print (self.treasure_chest_positions)

    #selecting bandits position from positions(avaliable positions)

        self.bandit_positions =random.sample(positions,5)


    def sett(self):
        self.blink = False
        self.guesses = 0
        self.end_tick = False
        self.tick()

    def get_pos(self):
        self.used = False
        xy = random.randrange(self.gridrange), random.randrange(self.gridrange)
        if xy in self.treasure_pos or xy in self.bandit_pos:
            self.used = True
            while self.used == True:
                xy = (random.randrange(self.gridrange), random.randrange(self.gridrange))
                if xy not in self.treasure_pos or xy in self.bandit_pos:
                    self.used = False
                    return xy

        else:
            return xy


    def gomoves(self,event=None):
        print ('GO MOVES')

    #Validate Moves so that the values of moves should lie inside the positions avaliable

        print (self.moves.get())
        print (self.dir.get())

    #On moving update the current position variable
    #Please deal with the position written in format label(row_no)(column_no) like label01 for row=0 and column=1 it will not be that difficult

        current_row= int(self.current_position[5:6])
        current_column=int(self.current_position[6:7])
        print (current_row , current_column)

    #now update the position based on moves if moves are invalid then pop up tkDialogBox search a little on google you will get help from there

    #self.current_position =

    def key_pressed(self, event):
        if event.keysym == "Right" and self.current_pos[1] < 7:
            self.current_pos[1] += 1
            print("right")
        elif event.keysym == "Left" and self.current_pos[1] > 0:
            self.current_pos[1] -= 1
            print("left")
        elif event.keysym == "Up" and self.current_pos[0] > 0:
            self.current_pos[0] -= 1
            print("up")
        elif event.keysym == "Down" and self.current_pos[0] < 7:
            self.current_pos[0] += 1
            print("down")
        elif event.keysym == "Return":
            self.process_guess()
        self.display_grid()
        self.matrix = [["#" for col in range(8)] for row in range(8)] # is here the best place for this?

    def check(self):
        if self.current_pos_tuple in self.treasures_won:
            self.counts = Counter(self.treasures_won)
            print (self.counts)
            print (self.counts)[self.current_pos_tuple]

            if self.current_pos_tuple in self.last_treasure:
                self.gold_found -= 10
                self.treasures_won.remove(self.current_pos_tuple)
                self.guesses -= 1
                self.last_treasure.remove(self.current_pos_tuple)
                print (self.last_treasure)
            if self.counts[self.current_pos_tuple] > 3:
                self.treasure_pos.remove(self.current_pos_tuple)
                self.bandit_pos.append(self.current_pos_tuple)
                print ('someone was here waiting for me')
                self.gold_found -= 10
                print (self.gold_found)

        if self.gold_found >= self.winscore:
            print ('you win')

        if len(self.treasure_pos) <= 0:
            print ('you lose')


    def process_guess(self):
        self.guesses += 1
        self.score_lbl.config(text="Guesses: " + str(self.guesses))
        self.current_pos_tuple = tuple(self.current_pos)
        print (self.current_pos_tuple)

        if self.current_pos_tuple in self.treasure_pos:
            self.check()
            print ('i think i see something shiney')
            self.gold_found += 10
            print (self.gold_found)
            self.treasures_won.append(self.current_pos_tuple)
            self.last_treasure.append(self.current_pos_tuple)
            self.end_tick = True
            self.gold_lbl.config(text="Gold: " + str(self.gold_found))
            self.matrix[self.current_pos_tuple[0]][self.current_pos_tuple[1]] = "$"
            self.display_grid()                                
        elif self.current_pos_tuple in self.bandit_pos:

            print ('something looks suspisious')
            self.gold_found = 0
        #if not (self.current_pos[0] == self.treasure_pos[0] and self.current_pos[1] == self.treasure_pos[1]):
                #print "NOT HERE"

        else:
            randinteger = random.randrange(10)
            dist = int(round(math.sqrt((self.current_pos[0] - self.treasure_pos[randinteger][0]) ** 2 + (self.current_pos[1] - self.treasure_pos[randinteger][1]) ** 2)))
            self.matrix[self.current_pos[0]][self.current_pos[1]] = str(dist)
            self.display_grid()
            print (' i cant seem to find anything')
            self.end_tick = True

    def display_grid(self):
        '''Displays current visual game state'''
        self.island.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        m_str = ""
        for row in range(len(self.matrix)):
            m_str += (" ".join(self.matrix[row]) + "\n")
        self.island.insert(1.0, m_str)


    def finish(self):
        self.matrix[self.treasure_pos[self.current_pos_tuple][0]][self.treasure_pos[self.current_pos_tuple][1]] = "$"
        self.display_grid()
        self.island.insert(tk.END, " + 10 Gold!")

        self.sett()



    def update(self,event=None):
        print (event.num)
        screenx=self.pos_frame.winfo_width()
        screeny=self.pos_frame.winfo_height()

        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):
                x='label'+str(i)+str(j)
                if x in self.treasure_chest_positions:
                    try:
                        self.x=tk.Label(self.pos_frame,bg="#"+"F"+str(5*(1+i))[0]+str(4*(i+1))[0]+str(6*(j+2))[0]+str(2*(j+1))[0]+"7",text='Treasure')
                        self.x.grid(row=i,column=j,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
                    except:
                        print("Treasure error")    

                elif x in self.bandit_positions:
                    self.x=tk.Label(self.pos_frame,bg="#"+"F"+str(5*(1+i))[0]+str(4*(i+1))[0]+str(6*(j+2))[0]+str(2*(j+1))[0]+"7",text='Bandit')
                    self.x.grid(row=i,column=j,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
                elif x==self.current_position:
                    self.x=tk.Label(self.pos_frame,bg="#"+"F"+str(5*(1+i))[0]+str(4*(i+1))[0]+str(6*(j+2))[0]+str(2*(j+1))[0]+"7",text='Current')
                    self.x.grid(row=i,column=j,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
                else:
                    self.x=tk.Label(self.pos_frame,bg="#"+"F"+str(5*(1+i))[0]+str(4*(i+1))[0]+str(6*(j+2))[0]+str(2*(j+1))[0]+"7",text=str(i)+str(j))
                    self.x.grid(row=i,column=j,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)

    def tick(self):
            '''timer for blinking cursor'''
            if self.blink == False:
                    self.matrix[self.current_pos[0]][self.current_pos[1]] = "#"
            elif self.blink == True:
                    self.matrix[self.current_pos[0]][self.current_pos[1]] = " "
            self.blink = not self.blink
            self.display_grid()
            if not self.end_tick:
                    root.after(300, self.tick)
            else:
                    self.sett()


def generate_initial_position():
    pos=str(random.randint(0,7))+str(random.randint(0,7))
    return pos


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
#app.master.title('Game')
root.mainloop()
```

I have a big problem because the code does not want to function while self.gridrange=8 is a tuple it needs to be an integer and I dont know what more you can do to make it an integer

This is the error

```
()
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Zero Davila\Desktop\new.py", line 110, in letsplay
    self.createWidgets()
  File "C:\Users\Zero Davila\Desktop\new.py", line 123, in createWidgets
    self.matrix = [["#" for col in range(self.gridrange)] for row in range(self.gridrange)]
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh() This is just so I could post on stack the h's

Comment: this is the whole code self.gridrange=8 should be an integer but is identified as a tuple anyone who helps i appreciate it a million

Comment: Your piece of code is huge. Please, try to reduce it first.

Comment: I did reduce in my other posts but no-one offered advice so i thought I would just post the whole code

Comment: To downvoters: While the code is lenghty, I am upvoting this question because it is salvageable and worth answering. Yes, the OP needs to be told how to fix his question, but the way to do that is to write a comment, not to downvote just because he has pasted too much code. His question is actually easily understood to know what his problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Your previous posts were incorrect. You did not assign `self.gridrange` as

```
self.gridrange = 8
```

You assign it as:

```
self.gridops = tk.Listbox(self.opwin, selectmode='SINGLE')
self.gridops.pack()
for i in range(6, 14):
    self.gridops.insert(tk.END, i)
self.gridrange = self.gridops.curselection()
```

If you read through the information for [`Listbox.curselection()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm) or the [actual source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2625-L2627), you'll find that it returns a tuple. Hence your problem.

However, in the future, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help in debugging. It would have helped immensely.